# SQLite3 database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Hello everyone i got this error while trying to create a table in my database, have checked my query carefully but could not understand where the problem is:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Subreddit (subreddit VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,name_name VARCHAR(15), FOREIGN KEY(name_name) REFERENCES Name(name), subreddit_id VARCHAR(15) );
Error: near "subreddit_id": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table constraints must come after all column definitions. You are declaring a column `subreddit_id` after you specify a foreign key constraint, which is invalid syntax.

Simply swap the definition of `subreddit_id` and the `FOREIGN KEY` definition.